# What is the best way to find text content under relatively indistinguishable tags by Selenium-webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

As newbie I prefer use Abs XPath to get find WebElemnts where text is positioned.
I tried:

```
List<WebElement> elements = web.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div/p"));
```

But i failed to catch text under tags with minor changes
Target xpaths:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div[8]/p
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div[3]/h3[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/ol[5]/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/strong[1]
```

What is correct formula or way to get all text content in the above mentioned xpaths ?

Comment: learn more on Xpath, use attribute on elements like class, id, href to get what you want. DONT USE xpath wih index

Comment: pasting html here would help to create xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear what you want: If you want all elements that contain direct text you could use:

```
/html/body[1]//*[text()[normalize-space()]]
```

this will return all elements with direct text()-nodes that after filtering unnecessary whitespace, have character-data.

meaning XPath-parts:

`//` = any descendant; see [this info on axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

`*` = any element

`[`some filter`]` = predicate to filter on direct previous node.

`[#number]` = the position within its siblings. `body[1]` maybe seems redundant, but can help the XPath-engine not to look any further for other `body` elements

`text()` = node of type text

`normalize-space()` = strips white-space according [this rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space)